# How to defeat the display info overlay on the HDMI output of the Canon XA25 including the status indicator?

Tags: streaming, live, canon

How to defeat the display info overlay on the HDMI output of the Canon XA25 including the status indicator.

An IT/AV colleague of mine needs to send the HDMI output of a Canon XA25 for streaming but can not get a completely clear video source void of the display overlay. He was able to shutdown everything else but the status light.

Actually two questions.

1) is it possible?

2) if so, how?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can find about it is to set the Output OnScreen Displays to Off in the settings.  If that isn't doing it, then I'm not sure that it is possible.

Comment: many thanks for responding. I am giving you a point for trying while waiting for my colleague to verify.

Comment: Bad news, my colleague's Canon XA25 was stolen from a locked closet early this week. I will have to suspend this question until he replaces the camera. My apologies.